# Intersect values based on a column value group

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R ( some sample values)

```
Account     Year_Month
200         201412
300         201412
200         201411
400         201411
200         201410
400         201410
200         201411
300         201412
```

I need to find out What was the frequency of an 'Account' in given year_months?

For example :

For 201412 (December 2014)

```
Account     Frequency count 
300         2
200         1
```

For 201412 and 201411 (December 2014 and November 2014)

```
Account   Frequency count  
300       2 
200       3 
400       1
```

I have tried making a factor on Year_Month but that did not work. What I may be missing? Any help?

Comment: Hard to say what concepts you are missing since you offered no code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#A simple solution is to use `table`.
```

`with(data,table(Account,Year_Month))` `# data is your data frame`

```
        201410 201411 201412
  200      1      2      1
  300      0      0      2
  400      1      1      0
OR
#data.table package
#install.packages("data.table) # if not installed
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(data)
dt[,list(freq=.N),c("Account","Year_Month")]
   Account Year_Month freq
1:     200     201412    1
2:     300     201412    2
3:     200     201411    2
4:     400     201411    1
5:     200     201410    1
6:     400     201410    1
```

Comment: My requirement is different, I need only two columns. in result, second column with frequency count has to combine given year months, as I explained in example

Comment: There are many options for that. I have used `data.table` package.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you wnat a function that can take multiple values for month and extract cases and then use `table` to return an R contingency table. Display in columnar format is supplied by the `as.data.frame.table` function.

```
 extract_yr.mon <- function(yr,mon,dat=dat){ 
                        table(dat[dat$Year_Month %in% paste0(yr, mon),"Account"])}

 extract_yr.mon(2014, 11:12, dat)
#    200 300 400 
#      3   2   1 

as.data.frame( extract_yr.mon(2014, 11:12, dat) )
#-------------
  Var1 Freq
1  200    3
2  300    2
3  400    1
```

You can add a name inside the table function if you don't like the "Var1" choice:

```
> extract_yr.mon <- function(yr,mon,dat=dat){ table(Account=dat[dat$Year_Month %in% paste0(yr, mon),"Account"])}
> as.data.frame( extract_yr.mon(2014, 11:12, dat) )
  Account Freq
1     200    3
2     300    2
3     400    1
```